# ImportError in bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson

i am making a python app in IBM bluemix,but when i pushed it,it had an error:

[image]

i found my python version is 2.7.10 ,so i thought maybe the reason is the too low,and i change the version to 3.5.1 in runtime.txt like this:

```
python-3.5.1
```

but it still didn't work and had the same error.I know I should install this package, but how can i install this in bluemix?
 Can anyone please give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah,I solved it. in bluemix, if you use some package that not as part of standard python package, you should write them in your requirements.txt, and then bluemix will download this package.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error, it says you are missing the `lxml` library.  This is not installed as part of the standard Python package, so you will need to install it with either `pip` or `conda`, depending on what you have setup.

```
pip install lxml
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `cf push`, if there is a `requirements.txt` file on your root folder, it will install all the dependencies on Bluemix.